# Is it possible to filter my collectionview by more than one field or column in a table in sql server database

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

In the code below, i can only filter based on the Surname column in my table, can i filter using more than one table column?

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(EmployeeView.ItemsSource);
        view.Filter = m => ((EmployeeMaster)m).Surname.ToLower().Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try combining the conditions via `&&` or `||` operators, like this:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(EmployeeView.ItemsSource); 
view.Filter = m => ((EmployeeMaster)m).Surname.ToLower().Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text.ToLower()) || ((EmployeeMaster)m).Name.ToLower().Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text.ToLower());
```